# LightSwitch Object Reference Issue during migration from VS2012 Update 3 to VS2013 Update 1 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, migration, visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2012

I have a LightSwitch project that compiles and runs in VS2012 Update 3 with no problems.  When attempting to migrate the project to VS2013 Update 1 RC the following error is generated:

*myprojectname*.lsxproj: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The migration log doesn't provide additional information, so don't know how to research, or debug/fix the problem.

The solution and project show in the 2013 Solution Explorer, but there are no folders or files under the project.

Under Windows Explorer, all of the folders and files exists, but clearly some have been modified because svn has flagged them as changed.  The backup created by the automated migration only contains the solution file, solution user options, and a packages folder - no other project files exist.

It appears that the issue may be with the Common project in the Common folder, because I'm able to independently open the Client and Server projects; however, when trying to open the Common project then the error above is generated.

Also, tried opening VS2013 in safe mode, and the migration of Common.csproj generated a different error:  The application which this project type is based on was not found.  However, created a new 2012 LightSwitch project, and tried opening Common.csproj in 2013, and received the same error relating to the application which this project type is based on was not found; therefore, I'm guessing that this is not the problem, and something else in the Common project is causing the object reference issue.

Any help on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you are using the release candidate (which is usually known to be buggy) and not the released version?

Comment: I can only find Update 1 RC.  Is there a RTM version?

Comment: I'm sorry I read it as just VS2013 not update 1.